# Python mystery about for loop and reduce

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, functional-programming

I'm trying to calculate byte entropy on an executable file. I first used for-loop for calculating it after getting histogram as an array. Then I tried using functools.reduce to fasten up a little bit. Interestingly I'm getting different results from the same array and same function, and I want to understand why.

I reduced it to a simple loop and two line code block but, I couldn't understand why one of them is wrong. I compared all elements of list "prob" and "prob" from the for-loop, all values are the same.

```
calc_entropy = lambda e,p: e - p*math.log(p,256) if (p != .0) else e

prob = hist / bytes_len
e = functools.reduce(calc_entropy, prob)
```

AND

```
e = .0
for freq in hist:
    prob = freq / bytes_len
    e = calc_entropy(e,prob)
```

One of them giving 0.813826598594107 other one is 0.8605594205272858. "hist" is a numpy.ndarray.

Comment: I would be nice if you gave `hist` and `bytes_len`.  You could use np.random with np.random.seed(123).

Comment: What is `dtype` in your `numpy.ndarray hist`? Is it `float` or integer type?

Comment: my guess: float precision in `/` are the problem here. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: @AlexYu it is numpy.float64

Comment: @FelixMartinez but, all "prob" values from loop equals to corresponding values in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial value is different.
In the loop version you first apply `calc_entropy(0, prob[0])`, but with reduce your first application is `calc_entropy(prob[0], prob[1])`. You can change that by calling `reduce` with an initial value: `reduce(calc_entropy, prob, 0)`.

Comment: Makes sense. Waiting for approval

Comment: Yes. You are correct - I made experiment with array of just 3 elements

Comment: That seems like a likely cause. I posted my experiments as an answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the initial value, as @YSelf pointed out in his answer.

Here is a demonstration:

```
import functools
import math
import numpy as np

calc_entropy = lambda e, p: e - p*math.log(p, 256) if (p != .0) else e

def f1a(hist, bytes_len):
    prob = hist / bytes_len
    e = functools.reduce(calc_entropy, prob)              # no initial value
    return e


def f1b(hist, bytes_len):
    prob = hist / bytes_len
    e = functools.reduce(calc_entropy, prob, 0.0)         # with initial value
    return e


def f2(hist, bytes_len):
    e = 0.0
    for freq in hist:
        prob = freq / bytes_len
        e = calc_entropy(e, prob)
    return e
```

Some tests (I only show one test, but I made several tests with different numbers, all with the same conclusion as below):

```
>>> b = 5
>>> h = np.random.rand(10)
>>> h
[0.68968912 0.37621079 0.76577699 0.06287911 0.49159805 0.63960027
 0.50323918 0.56442714 0.28445216 0.03391277]

>>> f1a(h, b)
0.4449530941371813
>>> f1b(h, b)
0.3562920060014537
>>> f2(h, b)
0.3562920060014537
```

Note how the result of `f1b()` and `f2()` are equal, but different from `f1a()`.